# Remote debugging using gdbserver over ssh

Tags: ssh, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I want to debug a process running on a remote box from my host box (I built the code on the host machine). 
Both have linux type operating systems.

I seems I can only communicate to the remote box from the host box via ssh (I tested using telnet).

**I have followed the following steps to set this up:**

**On the Remote box:**

1. Stop the firewall service:

   > service firewall_service stop
2. Attach the process to gdbserver

   > --attach :remote_port process_id

**On the Host box:**

3. Set up port forwarding via ssh

   > sudo ssh remote_username@remote_ip -L host_port:localhost:remote_port
   >   -f sleep 60m
4. Set up gdb to attach to a remote process:

   > gdb file.debug
   >
   > (gdb)    target remote remote_ip:remote_port

When I try to start the debugging on the host by running 'target remote remote_ip:remote_port' on the host box I get a 'Connection timedout' error.

Can you guys see anything I am doing wrong, anything to check or an alternative way to debug remotely over ssh I would be grateful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This command:

```
sudo ssh remote_username@remote_ip -L host_port:localhost:remote_port ...
```

forwards *local* host_port to remote_port on remote_ip's localhost. This is useful only if you could not just connect to remote_ip:remote_port directly (for example, if that port is blocked by firewall).

This command:

```
(gdb) target remote remote_ip:remote_port
```

asks GDB to connect to remote_port on remote_ip. But you said that you can only reach remote_ip via ssh, so it's not surprising that GDB times out.

What you want:

```
ssh remote_username@remote_ip -L host_port:localhost:remote_port ...
(gdb) target remote :host_port
```

In other words, you connect to *local* host_port, and ssh forwards that local connection to remote_ip:remote_port, where gdbserver is listening for it.

Comment: Thanks- I'll give it a try but it looks like there is another firewall between the 2 boxes which is probally why I'm not connecting.

Comment: First paragraph is wrong, "localhost" is evaluated on the ssh server, completely different from making a local connection to "localhost:remote_port".  The option `-L host_port:localhost:remote_port` is very useful for accessing ports on the SSH server other than the SSH port itself, bypassing any firewalls that might block them.